# AWS Elastic IP becomes detached after instance reboot

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-ip

I have Elastic IP, I have EC2 instance. If I reboot the instance elastic IP becomes detached. How can I make it persistent?

Answer (score 0):

Elastic IPs are not detached when you reboot an EC2 instance inside a VPC. They are also not detached when you stop then start your instance.

If you're using EC2-Classic and you stop, then start your instance it may be disassociated. EC2-Classic is really, really old now and probably should be upgraded.

From [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html)

When you stop a running instance, the following happens:
The instance retains its associated Elastic IP addresses. You're charged for any Elastic IP addresses associated with a stopped instance. With EC2-Classic, an Elastic IP address is dissociated from your instance when you stop it. For more information, see EC2-Classic.